# Find float values in dataframe and replace by range of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` and some columns have `NaN` values. I inputed `NaN` values with `KNNImputer`. Some values became floats but the column values are supposed to be categorical.

How do I replace these float values with a value from the set of values found in the columns?

Ex.

```
X = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 3, 1, 5, 2.89999, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5]})
```

Where `2.89999` is replaced with a value from the set `[1,3,5]`.

Thanks.

Comment: `X['A'].astype(int)` ?

Comment: I dont want to convert integer, I want to categorized a value from the set [1,3,5].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to coerce numbers to the nearest integer value, you'll want to round the values in the column to the nearest whole number before converting them to integers. Otherwise, your fractional values would all be truncated instead of rounded.

```
X['A'] = X['A'].round().astype(int)
```

---

If, on the other hand, you want any float value to be coerced to the nearest value in a given set like (1, 3, 5), then you can write a function to map float values to that specific set, then apply that function to your dataframe.

```
def coerce(x):
    if x <= 2.0:
        return 1
    elif x >= 4.0:
        return 5
    else:
        return 3

X = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3, 1, 5, 2.89999, 3, 1, 3, 1, 5, 2.0001, 8.9673]})

X['A'] = X.apply(lambda row: coerce(row['A']), axis=1)
print(X)
```

Comment: 8.9673    ----->    5    (not 9) and
2.0001    ----->    3    (not 2)

Comment: Thanks for help **Bill the Lizard**.

But my dataframe have 15 features. Each column is categorical and has different range. What can I do in this situation? Do I define different functions for each column?

Comment: @NerminÖZCAN Yes, having different functions to unpack different columns is pretty common.